# Get warmest and coldest temperature from the database

Tags: sql, sorting

I want to get the warmest and coldest temperature from the database but `ORDER BY data_temperature` with `ASC` or `DESC` and `SELECT MAX(data_temperature) FROM ...` doesn't work. I'm only getting `10.0` with `ORDER BY data_temperature DESC` and `9.9` with `ASC`. `MAX(data_temperature)` doesn't show any data at all.

When I sort the temperatures in phpMyAdmin, it shows the same value so I must scroll down to the warmest temperature which is `28.6`. The coldest temperature is `5.8`.

Here's how `data_temperature` looks like:

`data_temperature varchar(8) NOT NULL`

How can I get the warmest and coldest temperature from the database?

Comment: Your temperature is a character.... rather than a number. Please always store numbers as, well... numbers. Convert your character to a number and try again. If you tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using then someone will be able to help.

Comment: @Ben Many thanks! I have changed from `VARCHAR(8)` to `DECIMAL(10,1)` and now it works perfectly with `ORDER BY data_temperature` with `DESC` (warmest) or `ASC` (coldest).

Answer (score 2):

A VARCHAR will not sort the same way as a numeric value, so you need to convert the value.

```
CAST(data_temperature AS DECIMAL(6,2))
```

You can do this just in your ORDER BY if you want, or you can just select the MIN/MAX:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(data_temperature AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
      ,MIN(CAST(data_temperature AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

Varchar is the problem.  Cast it to a numeric type.

```
--Gets Max Temp
SELECT MAX(Cast(data_temperature AS FLOAT)) FROM TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert varchar to numeric.Assuming you are using sql server try this query,

```
select MAX(CAST(data_temperature AS Decimal(10,2)))
      ,MIN(CAST(data_temperature AS Decimal(10,2))) 
from temp
```

[SQlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc209/4)